# Errors with SSL certificates

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I need to use SSl certificates to establish a secure connection between a client and the server.

To create the certificates I used the commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key root.key -sha256 -days 365 -out root.pem
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -nodes -key client.key -sha256 -days 365 -out client.csr
openssl req -new -nodes -key server.key -sha256 -days 365 -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365 -sha256
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

These commands created the files:

- client.csr
- client.key
- root.key
- root.pem
- root.srl
- server.csr
- server.key

My client has the code:

```
s= requests.session()
s.cert= ("../certificates/client.csr" , "../certificates/client.key")
s.verify = "../certificates/root.pem"

urllib3.disable_warnings()

resp = s.post('https://localhost:5000/', json = token)
```

It returns the error:

```
(...)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
(...)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
(...)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

And my server has the code:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('../certificates/server.crt', '../certificates/server.key')
context.load_verify_locations('../certificates/root.pem')
context.verify_mode= ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, ssl_context=context, threaded=True)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you are using self signed Cert , you need to disable Cert check using something as:

```
requests.post('XXXXXXX', verify=False)
```

Comment: It returns the error:
`requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:645)`

Comment: now That means the server does not like your client certificate.

Comment: make sure to install latest version from openssl and if you on MAC install openssl using Homebrew and then regenerate the Certs

Comment: what can I do if the server doesn't like my client's certificate?

Comment: TLS 1.2 support is from OpenSSL version 1.0.1 , maybe you can start from here

Comment: i have this version `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`